# Why does grep print out unexpected output when file contains carriage returns?

Tags: grep

When I run grep like this, I can see the matches as expected:

```
$> echo -ne 'foo\nfoo\n' > file_a
$> grep -Hn foo file_a
file_a:1:foo
file_a:2:foo
```

But when I create a file with carriage returns in it, grep gives me unexpected output:

```
$> echo -ne '\x0dfoo\x0dfoo\nfoo\n' > file_b
$> grep -Hn foo file_b
fooe_b:1:
file_b:2:foo
```

Can anyone explain why it gives this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unexpected. The carriage return moves the cursor to the start of the line.  `grep` has already printed out the file's name and the line number, and the contents of the matching line overwrites this (due to the carriage return before and after the first `foo` on the line).

Carriage returns may also be written as `\r`:

```
printf '\rfoo\rfoo\nfoo\n' >file
```

This will create a file with two lines.  The first line will contain the word `foo` twice, but the carriage returns will move the cursor to the start of the line. If using `cat`to view this file, it will look as if there's only one `foo` on the first line.